Hitting a URL using express is giving me ERR_BAD_REQUEST
I have a url https://leetcode.com/_next/data/xVVXH3Clo8h3_-5OShKCy/contest.json which when i try to access via a web(using chrome/firefox...) I am getting the desired output

but when i try to do the same using express and axios I am getting an unexpected error

I thought this was a cors error so i tried using cors-anywhere but it didn't help.Cant seem to understand the error and why I am getting it
The complete error :
error => AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403
    at settle (file:///Users/akashbhandari/Desktop/myProjects/react/CPUnified-server/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:19:12)
    at Unzip.handleStreamEnd (file:///Users/akashbhandari/Desktop/myProjects/react/CPUnified-server/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:572:11)
    at Unzip.emit (node:events:529:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1400:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': undefined,
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.5.1',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://leetcode.com/_next/data/xVVXH3Clo8h3_-5OShKCy/contest.json',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: true,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    strictContentLength: false,
    _contentLength: 0,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'leetcode.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 9,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'leetcode.com',
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: null,
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      write: [Function: writeAfterFIN],
      [Symbol(alpncallback)]: null,
      [Symbol(res)]: null,
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 5602,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: null,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 60,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 9043,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 216,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    _header: 'GET /_next/data/xVVXH3Clo8h3_-5OShKCy/contest.json HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/1.5.1\r\n' +
      'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
      'Host: leetcode.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 0,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
    path: '/_next/data/xVVXH3Clo8h3_-5OShKCy/contest.json',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      rawTrailers: [],
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 403,
      statusMessage: 'Forbidden',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: true,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'https://leetcode.com/_next/data/xVVXH3Clo8h3_-5OShKCy/contest.json',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 46,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'leetcode.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://leetcode.com/_next/data/xVVXH3Clo8h3_-5OShKCy/contest.json',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'accept-encoding': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    },
    [Symbol(errored)]: null,
    [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
    [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
    [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
  },
  response: {
    status: 403,
    statusText: 'Forbidden',
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      date: 'Mon, 08 Apr 2024 14:32:44 GMT',
      'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      connection: 'close',
      'accept-ch': 'Sec-CH-UA-Bitness, Sec-CH-UA-Arch, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version, Sec-CH-UA-Mobile, Sec-CH-UA-Model, Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version-List, Sec-CH-UA-Platform, Sec-CH-UA, UA-Bitness, UA-Arch, UA-Full-Version, UA-Mobile, UA-Model, UA-Platform-Version, UA-Platform, UA',
      'cross-origin-embedder-policy': 'require-corp',
      'cross-origin-opener-policy': 'same-origin',
      'cross-origin-resource-policy': 'same-origin',
      'origin-agent-cluster': '?1',
      'permissions-policy': 'accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),browsing-topics=(),camera=(),clipboard-read=(),clipboard-write=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),hid=(),interest-cohort=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),payment=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),serial=(),sync-xhr=(),usb=()',
      'referrer-policy': 'same-origin',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'cf-mitigated': 'challenge',
      'cf-chl-out': 'xYKX9Z18UrdMVF/Mr0H5blgxyUW3mQaX4zhwScB0bbX7Ax/Es8HRZKT8upkL+pwMtZzPaBndfZKk2OvacJSxY3APHYcVcoQZOvh6IeI4nzSVkeJnh48rygSJl+pJTy3w5lfG74hFv9M8kvtfOD4h6w==$Bo0ax177rCtJv1ooXBO/6Q==',
      'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
      expires: 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT',
      'set-cookie': [Array],
      vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      server: 'cloudflare',
      'cf-ray': '8712f7eeac7747c0-BOM'
    },
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: [Array],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      env: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [Object [AxiosHeaders]],
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://leetcode.com/_next/data/xVVXH3Clo8h3_-5OShKCy/contest.json',
      data: undefined
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET /_next/data/xVVXH3Clo8h3_-5OShKCy/contest.json HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.5.1\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: leetcode.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      path: '/_next/data/xVVXH3Clo8h3_-5OShKCy/contest.json',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'leetcode.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
      [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
}```


CORS is a client-side thing, node wouldn't be affected by it. If the same request fails on node that's probably a deliberate block by them. Usually there's more information in the response body

You've to set the User-Agent, Host and Cookie in the axios config header:


axios.get('https://leetcode.com/_next/data/xVVXH3Clo8h3_-5OShKCy/contest.json', {
    headers: {
        'Host': 'leetcode.com',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:110.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0.',
        'Cookie': '__cf_bm=some_token'
    }
})



The reason why its returning 403 forbidden error is because the actual response is meant for browsers. So, you've to mimic the browser behaviour by setting the config headers.

this worked for me can you give an in detail answer or provide any kind of documentation/blog

@reedrichards
You're getting 403 Forbidden error probably because the leetcode server is allowing "valid" requests (only from browsers). A server can try to identify whether the request is coming from a browser by checking some of the HTTP request headers like Host, User-Agent, etc.
So, by setting these headers in the axios config, we can "trick" the server in believing that our incoming request (via axios) is a valid request, i.e is coming from a browser.
